# Is there a word/name for the node(s) in a graph with the minimal cumulative path length to a set of other nodes?

Tags: terminology, graphs

In other words, given a graph with nodes $N=\{n_0,n_1,...,n_j\}$, and a set of nodes in the graph $M=\{n_a,n_b,...,n_k\}$ with $M\subseteq N$, I'm looking for what to call the node or nodes $n'$ which minimize:

$\sum_{m\in M}d_{min}(n',m)$

where $d_{min}(x,y)$ is the shortest distance from node $x$ to node $y$, as traditionally defined.

When $M=N$, this would be the node with the highest closeness centrality, but I'm interested in subgraphs.

Comment: Why not the vertices closest to $M$?  See also [graph centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Closeness_centrality).

Comment: Nit-picky note: using typical conventions, your sum ranges over $a, a+1, \dots, k$ -- not what you want. I recommend you use an index set $I \subseteq [0..j]$ so that $M = \{ n_i \mid i \in I\}$.

Comment: @Raphael Even more nits picked. No need to introduce indices at all: $\sum_{x\in M} d_\min(n',x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the nitpicks; it's been a while since I wrote math so formally :)